# Apache POI Update Custom Fields

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, apache-poi

I have successfully used IKVM.NET to create a .NET DLL for Apache POI, then used it successfully to update properties of a Microsoft Word 2003 document - the author and company and some custom fields.

The document references some of these fields in its content.

For example

Ref: Your account number *[account number held in a custom field]*

When you open the document you have to right-click on the field and "Update field" for it to show the new information written to it by POI.

For some documents this is not a big deal but there are going to be some with 20+ custom fields which all will need updating. By hand is not a very preferable option.

Any way in POI to update the fields so they're correct when the document opens? Or do I need to resort to a macro of some sort that fires when the document opens?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever found a way how to accomplish this with POI ?

Comment: @toong no I didn't, I actually ended up using the Microsoft OpenXML libraries to create a .docx file using text replacement within the paragraphs and not the custom fields.